# switchee and regex

Tags: structure, regex

I use in a EE site Structure and Low events. I need to use switchee but I can't find the correct regex for a date format like this: yyyy-mm
I use quit often this switchee regex: {case value="#^P(\d+)$#|''"} for paging but I just can't find it for I need: {case value="yyyy-mm|''"}

Answer (score 1):

For a not too specific match try:

```
{case value="#\d{4}-\d{2}#"}
```

which would match 4 digits ( \d{4} ) then a dash ( - ) then 2 digits ( \d{2} ).

UPDATE:
Forgot about encoding brackets in switchee regex, one of these should work:

```
{case value="#\d\d\d\d-\d\d#"}
```

or

```
{case value="#\d&#123;4&#124;-\d&#123;2&#124;#"}
```

The second version replaces the brackets with `&#123;` for { and `&#124;` for } .

Comment: I'm afraid switchee does not accept this characters, { }, in the regex.

Comment: Thanks Romans, but what I want does work. On my first page with events it's working just perfect but if my URL is .../agenda/2014-11 I get a 404 page. I thought that Structure would work with switchee but it does not. Structure does understand the paging and when it's empty {case value="#^P(\d+)$#|''"} but not with a date yyyy-mm

Comment: What is the exact value of the variable you're using in switchee where it's not working: /agenda/2014-11 ?

Comment: I use Structure and LowEvents.
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_3}" parse="inward"}

{case value="#^P(\d+)$#|''"}

Listing agenda items by month. Structure ignore segment_3 is this one is a paging and I want structure to also ignore segment_3 if this one looks like yyyy-mm

{/case}

{case default="Yes"}

Detail agenda items. If segment_3 is not a paging, not empty and not somethings like yyyy-mm show the detail of one item

{/case}